# Rewriting and location in nginx

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I am currently facing a stunningly strange issue.

I have a site running at xyz.com , which is rooted in /var/www/xyz.com/ . Now in addition, I have an admin interface to that app which is meant to be running on xyz.com/admin and which finds its root in /var/www/xyz.com/admin/ .

However, the scripts in /var/www/xyz.com/admin/ require that precisely this directory be run as the root directory (by relative addressing with slashes in front). I do not want to change the script. Now the problematic issue is this:

1. If I set a root location for /admin/ to be /var/www/xyz.com/ , the admin page will be called correctly, but the scripts will not work.
2. If I set a root location for /admin/ to be /var/www/xyz.com/admin/ , the page cannot be addressed (resulting in an error log entry due to an access
   attempt at /var/www/xyz.com/admin/admin/ ).

How do I eliminate this issue with the use of my nginx (without modifying the admin script)? Can anyone help?

Edit: I do actually work via upstream for the main location "/", so it is no choice to just leave out the extra block.

Comment: Use subdomain `admin.xyz.com`

Comment: Thought of that. Do not have a valid TLS cert though.

Comment: Well, get it. There are cheap (and even free) SSL cerificates available.

Comment: Got it. But I've also read through StartSSL's terms and conditions and decided it would not fit. No other way?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I can see two solutions here.

First one is to replace `root` to `alias` http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias

```
location /admin/ {
     alias /var/www/xyz.com/admin/;
     ...
}
```

So in this example `$document_root` inside `/admin/` location will be `/var/www/xyz.com/admin/`.

And second solution (I dont know why, but mat be you will find it usefull). How PHP know about document root? With DOCUMENT_ROOT fastcgi parameter. Inside `fastcgi.conf` you can see string `fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $document_root;`. And this parameter can be redifined in your config

```
location /admin/ {
     include fastcgi.conf;
     fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /my/new/root/;
     ...
}
```

First solution is much better, so I placed second one just for show what is document root in PHP and how it's work.